# Javascript method that receives a value from a servlet not working

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, jstl

I have a JavaScript method that on the document body `onload()` event should show an alert.

It has one string parameter that the servlet provides. The method does get the value but it doesn't do anything so I don't know if my logic is wrong or if there is a limitation to doing this in HTML.

The code for my script:

```
function Check1(temp) {
    if (temp.toString().length > 5) {
        jAlert('success', 'This is the success dialog.', 'Success Dialog');
    }         
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<body onload="Check1(<c:out value="${CFP}"/>)">
    <div id="main">
```

Servlet code:

```
Fmsg = "Fornecedor " + ID + " - " + nome + " foi criado";         
request.setAttribute("CFP",Fmsg);
userPath = "/Fornecedor";
```

So any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try wrapping the value with quotes: `onload="Check1('<c:out value="${CFP}"/>')";` so that it's passed as string.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function you're expecting `temp` to be a string value. Imagine that `${CFP}` returns a string value of `Fornecedor 1 - somenome foi criado`, then the

```html
<body onload="Check1(<c:out value="${CFP}"/>)">
```

would be generated as follows

```html
<body onload="Check1(Fornecedor 1 - somenome foi criado)">
```

*(to see it yourself, open page in browser, rightclick and View Source)*

This is invalid JavaScript syntax. You actually want to pass a literal string as function argument. In that case your function should ultimately look like this:

```html
<body onload="Check1('Fornecedor 1 - somenome foi criado')">
```

Now, let's backport that to the JSP code which is responsible for generating that HTML/JS code:

```html
<body onload="Check1('<c:out value="${CFP}"/>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "HTML" you literally mean .html file, then yes, it's a limitation.

You were trying to put JSP (specifically, the `<c:out />` tag) in a plain .html file, which does not work, unless you've configured your Servlet container to treat .html files as JSPs (which to be honest, I'm not even sure is possible).

Comment: Sorry for the html part what i really wanted to write was jsp.